# Why is my Xamarin Forms iOS app crashing when using Microsoft Azure Mobile Services

Tags: c#, azure, xamarin.forms, azure-mobile-services

I am having a strange problem with my Xamarin Forms app that I can't seem to solve, I seem to be going around in circles with it instead.  It seems to be tied to my iOS project specifically and it surrounds the assembly reference `Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Mobile`.  When I run my app on my iPhone simulator and then try to view any part of it that gets data from Azure the following message is triggered.

> System.InvalidOperationException: A Microsoft Azure Mobile Services
>   assembly for the current platform was not found. Ensure that the
>   current project references both Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Mobile and the
>   following platform-specific assembly:
>   Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Mobile.Ext.

I find this strange because I have installed what I believe to be all the correct references which are:

Entire solution used `Xamarin.Forms v2.3.4.247`

**MyApp(Portable)**

- `WindowsAzure.MobileServices 1.3.2`
- `WindowsAzure.MobileService.SQLiteStore 1.0.1`

**MyApp.iOS**

- `Microsoft.Azure.Mobile.Client 4.0.1`
- `Microsoft.Azure.Mobile.Client.SQLiteStore 4.0.1`

I thought perhaps the app.config of the iOS project was corrupt or perhaps missing some information when I'd installed these nuget packages so I have a quick look and it all looked like it should.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Net.Http" publicKeyToken="b03f5f7f11d50a3a" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-1.5.0.0" newVersion="1.5.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Newtonsoft.Json" publicKeyToken="30ad4fe6b2a6aeed" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-10.0.0.0" newVersion="10.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="PInvoke.BCrypt" publicKeyToken="9e300f9f87f04a7a" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-0.5.0.0" newVersion="0.5.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Validation" publicKeyToken="2fc06f0d701809a7" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-2.4.0.0" newVersion="2.4.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
     <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Mobile" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-1.3.0.0" newVersion="1.3.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Net.Http.Primitives" publicKeyToken="b03f5f7f11d50a3a" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.2.29.0" newVersion="4.2.29.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
</configuration>
```

I can provide more code if needed but I wanted to keep the problem localised to what I have seen and where it reports the problem to be.  Does anyone know what could be causing this or what I need to do to resolve it? Could it perhaps be versions that are causing the problem and should I consider rolling back?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AFAIK, [WindowsAzure.MobileServices](https://www.nuget.org/packages/WindowsAzure.MobileServices/) is now deprecated and it used to work with Mobile Services (domain like **{your-app-name}.azure-mobile.net**). While [Microsoft.Azure.Mobile.Client](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Azure.Mobile.Client) is used to work with Mobile Apps (App Service, domain like **{your-app-name}.azurewebsites.net**).

> Does anyone know what could be causing this or what I need to do to resolve it? Could it perhaps be versions that are causing the problem and should I consider rolling back?

I noticed that the app.config of your iOS project has the `dependentAssembly` about Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Mobile with the newVersion 1.3.0.0.

Per my understanding, you have installed both WindowsAzure.MobileServices and Microsoft.Azure.Mobile.Client packages, I would recommend you using the same package to narrow this issue. Also, you need to initialize azure mobile by the following code before you using `MobileServiceClient`:

```
Microsoft.WindowsAzure.MobileServices.CurrentPlatform.Init();
```

Moreover, I checked my xamarin.forms application which has installed [Microsoft.Azure.Mobile.Client 3.1.0](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Azure.Mobile.Client/3.1.0), it could work as expected. Here is the git sample about [azure-mobile-apps-quickstarts](https://github.com/Azure/azure-mobile-apps-quickstarts/tree/master/client/xamarin.forms), you could refer to it.
Additionally, here is a similar git issue, you could refer to it [here](https://github.com/Azure/azure-mobile-apps-net-client/issues/271).

Comment: I downgraded my `Microsoft.Azure.Mobile.Client` so that I could install it on my shared project and that seemed to work.  This will have to tide me over until Xamarin update their documentation to reflect these deprecated libraries.